# Android application to send a simple form to a web service and get an sms in return

Tags: c#, android, webforms

I'm trying to write an android application with a simple form. The user will send a string to a server and will get an SMS back with the same string + "thank you!".

I know Java but I'm more fluent in C#. I did manage to send the string to the web-service.

On Android Client:

```
public void sendFeedback(View button) { 
    final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);  
    String name = nameField.getText().toString();  
    postData(name);
}

public void postData(String name) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:53811/WinnerSite/WebService.asmx?op=WriteToDB");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", name));
        //  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println(response.getFirstHeader(getPackageName()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Web-Service is pretty slim:

```
[WebMethod]
public string WriteToDB(string json)
{
    return "Hello World "+ json;
}
```

I ran the web-service with Visual-Studio built in server service.
The code behind the application got the string properly, but the code never recieved the string. Does someone has an idea what could be the problem?

the next phase, I cannot find the SMS email gate to SMS from my web-service SMS to one of the following Israeli operators:

- Orange (a.k.a Partner)
- Cellcom

Can someone help me find that gate?

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.but("name",name)
```

and in the server send a message by using

```
json_encode("name than you ");
```

that may help you

Comment: But I jsut want to try POC with a simple string.
Any other idea?